# How can I use a command button to update a range of cells based on their current values in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, button

I am working in Excel and trying to create a command button that will update the value in a cell based on the current value of the cell, down the entire column.

More specifically, I have a column with location IDs which are integers. At a click, I want all cells within that column that contain the values 1 or 2 to be changed to 10. Then, I want to run a prerecorded sort macro.

I have found information on cascading If statements, which seems to be the key. I thought something like the following might work, but it keeps telling me I have a logic error.

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("LocationID") = 1 Then
       Range("LocationID") = 10
    Else
        If Range("LocationID") = 2 Then
           Range("LocationID") = 10
    End If
End Sub`

Location is the column I am trying to search and change.I have not added my sort macro into this yet, because I assume that works like any other button that calls a macro.

This is probably really basic, but VBA is totally foreign to me. I've been banging my head against this problem all morning. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use the macro recorder to give you some code to start with.

Comment: I can record the sort function. That part is easy.  What I am having trouble with is getting it to search the column for all cells with the specified values and then change them. I don't think I can record that kind of code logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you mean something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Dim lRow As Long
      lRow = 1

      Do Until Range("A" & lRow) = ""
        Select Case Range("A" & lRow)
          Case 1, 2
            Range("A" & lRow) = 10
        End Select
        lRow = lRow + 1
      Loop
End Sub
```

Note: I just guessed that it's column A. You will want to change that in all 3 places to the column that has the value you want.